# How /login works in Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

> Refferring above url, It creates a application secured by spring security. It makes the "/","home","/login" not secured, so that those are accessible to everyone.
>
> Step 1 . It maps "/login" to login. I understand that on a request coming from browser(get method) would show the view login (login.html)

```
 registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
```

> Step 2 .But then on login.html it again have the submit url "/login" , wouldn't it submit the page again to handler mapping in step 1 and show the same view ??

```
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
```

> Step 3. The doumentation further says that Spring security would filter the request and aunthenticate it, but why ? /login is not secured. and method name was not registerd in step 1 ( so it should handle all get and post).
>
> Please help to understand this, Thanks!

Comment: No it won't... The first is a  GET request, the other is a POST request. Both are handled differently.

Comment: You mean  registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login"); registers this as get ? But spring documentation says if no method is supplied it would be all methods (get, post, put ....etc) Thanks!

Comment: That only applies to `@RequestMapping` not whilst adding a view controller. Nonetheless it still would work like that as the filter from spring security reacts on to POST request on the configured URL.